# problem, how to start Android Bluetooth Socket connection?

Tags: android, sockets, bluetooth, connection

i want to implement an app where i can send data(object/file) through bluetooth Socket programming,, but m not getting the way where to start,

i have created

`private ArrayAdapter<String> mNewDevicesArrayAdapter;`

for storing scanned devices, in BroadCastReceiver{ ...onReceive()... where i have this code..

```
if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)) {
   // Get the BluetoothDevice object from the Intent                
     BluetoothDevice device = 
         intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);

   // Add the name and address to an array adapter to show in a ListView
 mNewDevicesArrayAdapter.add(device.getName() + "\n" + device.getAddress());
...}
```

and

```
String info = mNewDevicesArrayAdapter.getItem(0).toString();
```

// Get the device MAC address, which is the last 17 chars in the View

```
String address = info.substring(info.length() - 17);

System.out.println("In Auto   "+mNewDevicesArrayAdapter.toString());
System.out.println("In Auto    "+address);
```

this is successfully showing multiple scanned devices...

now i want to send data to all devices store in array,, not getting the way???

how do i manage UUIDs for multiple devices ?

and where i can code AcceptThread, connectedThread, ConnectThread from http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/wireless/bluetooth.html, in separate class or in the same class where i am searching for devices, because in the chat example i can see that mNewDeviceArrayAdapter is in DeviceListActivity Class, while the Threads are in BluetoothChatService Class,

and what more i have to do,?

if i want to accept data from multiple devices, as if all devices have my app running, so they can send and receive data to one another.

I Hope, the question is understandable to the readers, and those who knows the solution will guide me soon,

Thanks in Advance
Regards.